# Tensorflow mobilenet error Input layer not found: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Shape_5 in function 'connect'

Tags: tensorflow, opencv

I am trying to load my custom SSD into `opencv` and receive this error:

```
output[0,0,:,:].shape is (0, 1)
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-13uokl4r/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp (2562) parseNode DNN/TF: Can't parse layer for node='MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/strided_slice_7'. Exception: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-13uokl4r/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:616: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Shape_5 in function 'connect'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(c)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-13uokl4r/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:616: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found: MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Shape_5 in function 'connect'
```

.pxtxt file
https://easyupload.io/6na7k9

Comment: Hi! This Error replicated in this issue  too.  
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14496